# Error while creating PDF using XSL javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am getting the below error while creating a PDF using XSLT:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The id "wp1015280" already exists in this document

I am not able to get... what the error messaging is trying to say.
Can someone please help in identifying the error?

Answer (score 0):

"wp1015280" is present as the value of at least two `id` or `xml:id` attributes.  (More accurately, as the value of attributes that your schema or DTD says contains an ID or, if there is no schema, as the value of `xml:id` attributes, since that always contains an ID.)

If you can write your file to the filesystem then open it in an XML editor, the editor should be able to indicate where the duplicates occur.